# Three JS: I am getting this error Unsupported OpenType signature <!DO

Tags: javascript, fonts, three.js, truetype

I have a three js project, and I use **parcel** as module bundler. I try to load a font with THREE js **TTFLoader** but I get this error. I've looked up similar problem on the internet, some says that it has something to do with the **relative path** of the font, but I think it doesn't. I don't know where the problem actually is

**Here is the snapshot of the error**
[image]

**Here is the project tree:**

[image]

**Here is part of the code that contains error:**

**app.js**

```
// load font -- three font
const ttfLoader = new TTFLoader();

ttfLoader.load('fonts/Mont-Regular.ttf', (json) => {
   const font = new FontLoader(json);

   this.textGeo = new TextGeometry('Hello Text', {
      font: font,
      size: 200,
      height: 50,
      curveSegments: 12,
   });

   this.textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
   });

   this.textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeo, this.textMaterial);
   this.textMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
});

this.scene.add(this.textMesh);
```

---

**Here is the codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/three-project-0hpqjr

---

How can I solve this problem ? Thankyou

Comment: Why don’t you think the advice you’re getting online is correct? Your font parser is trying to parse `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which is not a font file; It’s the first line of HTML code when you reach a 404 error page. Either your path is incorrect, or the `.ttf` file is actually HTML with the wrong extension. Check your network tab in the developer tools, and see what address it’s trying to fetch from.

Comment: I got that error when I used FontLoader to load the typeface.json, I was also stuck with that, so I tried the TTFLoader, But I got another error message which is what I ask here. I've check the network in dev tool, and the font has status of 304 Not modified. And how to check if the .ttf font is actually HTML ? @Marquizzo

Comment: I use parcel as module bundler @Marquizzo

Comment: In your network tab, right-click the row where the .ttf is being requested. Select “copy URL”, then put that address on your browser address bar. What do you get?

Comment: I get nothing, It just loads root localhost path

Comment: would you mind checking out the codesandbox I've just provided @Marquizzo

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/three-project-0hpqjr

Comment: here is also link to the github if you want to run it on your local machine https://github.com/reynaldlamury/poetry100  @Marquizzo

Comment: With the way you have the directory structure on codesandbox, the correct font path seems to be `/src/fonts/Mont-Regular.ttf`. Also, the structure you have on codesandbox doesn't match the structure you list in your question. The font loading error goes away but a new, different error arises.

Comment: thank your for pointing that out, yes the file structure in the sandbox is different from what is listed in my question, that's because sandbox always put their main files under /src directory. But when the file structure and the font path are changed to match the codesandbox structure, it leads to new error. I never tried this before. But now I know that there is another potential problem @Ouroborus

Comment: I've just figured out that the problem is still the same. When I use absolute path like you suggested ```/src/fonts/Mont-Regular.ttf``` , the library is calling ```font.generateShapes()``` but the font is not loaded because its an absolute path I think. But when I changed the path to the relative path, I get the same error like the first time @Ouroborus

Comment: The font is loading otherwise you'd be getting the original error. That you have a different error now is likely because you have additional bugs. In this case [`FontLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/FontLoader) takes a callback that is called when the font finishes loading, but you aren't setting/using that callback and so the rest of your code is running to soon. (I'm not sure where you get `TTFLoader`, but it likely has the same capability.)

Comment: Could you be more specific which part of the code I should include in the callback. Can you give me an example or would you mind pointing it out in the codesandbox so I can see where I did wrong @Ouroborus

Comment: Everything that requires the font to be loaded first. You might find [this example](https://blog.mozvr.com/threejs-secretly-supports-true-type-fonts/) useful.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I've seen that article before, but Im not sure how to implement that since It has very minimal example and implementation. Can you give another reference @Ouroborus

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've figured out Where I did wrong, this time I use THREE **FontLoader** instead of TTFLoader, and I use absolute path from the root project directory. I put this add to scene code `this.scene.add(this.textMesh)`  inside the callback function. For the font, I used font example provided by the library: `'node_modules/three/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json'`  and  it uses absolute path

**Here is the code:**

```
const fontLoader = new FontLoader();
fontLoader.load(
  'node_modules/three/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',
   (Helvfont) => {
     // const font = fontLoader.parse(json);

    this.textGeo = new TextGeometry('Yeah', {
      font: Helvfont,
      size: 0.2,
      height: 0,
      // curveSegments: 12,
    });

    this.textMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    this.textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeo, this.textMaterial);
    this.textMesh.position.set(-0.5, 0.5, 0);
    this.scene.add(this.textMesh);
  },
);
```

But if want to load the .ttf font, you can just use TTFLoader to load the font and `FontLoader.parse()` to parse the json, because it converts .ttf font to json so you need to parse it before you can use it

**Here is the code:**

```
 const ttfLoader = new TTFLoader();
 const fontLoader = new FontLoader();

 ttfLoader.load('src/fonts/Mont-Regular.ttf', (json) => {
    const MontFont = fontLoader.parse(json);

    this.textGeo = new TextGeometry('Yeah', {
      font: MontFont,
      // font: Helvfont,
      size: 0.2,
      height: 0,
      // curveSegments: 12,
    });

    // this.textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    //   color: 0xff0000,
    //   side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    // });
    this.textMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    this.textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeo, this.textMaterial);
    this.textMesh.position.set(-0.5, 0.5, 0);
    this.scene.add(this.textMesh);
 });
```